# When I've to use the HEREMAPS REST API

Tags: api, maps, here-api

I'm new in here maps and don't know

**1- When I've to use the REST API instead of JavaScript API**
as I know the REST API returns only **xml or json** object!

Does it mean I'll have to use the JavaScript API to do visual effects?!!!

**2- also I don't know how to save the map to display it again to the user after he doing some changes on it.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- When I've to use the REST API instead of JavaScript API as I know the REST API returns only xml or json object so,
Does it mean I'll have to use the JavaScript API to do visual effects and what are the advantages of using REST?!!!
[TCS] : The HERE Maps API for JavaScript is a set of programming interfaces that enable developers to build Web applications with feature rich, interactive HERE Maps at their center. Whereas HERE REST APIs provide a flexible and fast access to variety of map data and functionalities. The HERE Maps API for JavaScript 3.0 exposes the functionality of a collection of RESTful Web Services in the following four core components.
Yes, the REST API only provides responses in form of XML or  JSON, to show it on a map you will need the Javascript API. You will find examples to explore on our playground on the link http://developer.here.com/api-explorer

2- How to create a drag-able route not a drag-able waypoint?
[TCS] : Dragable route is possible to implement , you will find an example on the following link
http://tcs.it.here.com/Examples/src/HLP3_Fleet.html

3- How to save the map to display it again to the user after he doing some changes?
[TCS] : We do not provide  as part of our product portfolio to store any user related data once a session is terminated. A custom solution will have to be developed at your side if you would like to save any changes done on a map by a user and show these again when the user returns to the map. 
If you would like to save the map as an image however that is possible using the 'Capture' functionality within the JS API. The following link also shows the Capture functionality

Comment: Answered by Jithin Krishnan from Here Maps